# Homomorphisms of group $\Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've just begun studying modern algebra and while studying group homomorphisms 
I'm having trouble answering these questions.

1. Find all homomorphisms $\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_4$.
2. Is $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb Z_4)=\{ \text{all homomorphisms $\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_4$} \}$ a group?
3. Find $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_4)$ and show that it is a group.
4. Find all generators for a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on these questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is generated by $1$ (it's a cyclic group), a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ is determined by where it sends $1$. How many choices do you have?
2. Think about the axioms of a group. In particular, every element of a group should be invertible. Is this true of all endomorphisms?
3. In 1 above you'll have determined all the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$. Which ones are automorphisms (i.e. isomorphisms).
4. What would the order of a generator be? Once you answer this, think about how the order of an element $m \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is related to $\gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: For 1. I've thought of 4. 0->0, 0->1, 0->2, 0->3 but isn't a homomorphism supposed to map identity element to an identity element? So I first thought 0 had to be fixed to 0. And I think all four are isomorphisms aren't they? And finally, I haven't completely understood the concept of order could you help me out?